# JSON Nested Lists

Tags: c#, android, json, list, unity-game-engine

I'm working on an app in Unity3d for android. I want to be able to save a grouping of different pieces of information in a JSON file. The data is in several lists. I have:

EventName, Date of Event,
MemberID, MemberName,
EquipmentID, Description

For each member id and name, it should have the equipment they use.
I'm new to json, so I'm not sure where to start.
I would imagine the number of members of the team would be auto-generated by the list.count.
Hopefully this has enough information to formulate an answer.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LiteJSON , create a new list , add everything you want in that list and then use LiteJSON mapper to create a JSON object and then save it using StreamWriter http://lbv.github.io/litjson/

Comment: I was planning to simply save the string in a SQLite database table.

Comment: well it should but not sure never checked ,i know that minijson does work with ios

Comment: No I haven't. Not yet. I think I should use a struct in the class that takes in one list and one array. (I'll convert the list to an array before I do). Then It should come together much easier. Too bad Unity3d doesn't let you AddRange with lists of different class types.

Comment: @KenGordon ok listen use the new unity 5.3 json serializor that converts objects to json 
public class DataToSave{
public list<string> names
}
 DataToSave saveItem = new DataToSave();
saveitem.names = new list<string>(){"john","skeet"};
string jsonText =  JsonUtility.ToJson(saveItem);

Now u have json text of your object and now save it to disk using system libraries

Comment: Thanks LumbusterTick!

Comment: @KenGordon please select the answer as answered your welcome